# I can't global install webpack - terminal says missing write access(I enabled root user)

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, terminal, global

[image: Global install webpack issue]

As the screenshot shows I have enabled root user and already did an npm init which did create a package.json

I was able to do a local install of webpack on my project through `npm i -D webpack`.

Its just the global install through `npm -g i webpack` that doesn't work.

For reference I am using a macbook pro with macOS High Sierra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by just putting sudo in front of npm -g i webpack to install globally. I was still a root user when I did this, but not sure if that helped.

Comment: This is not a good idea - running node modules as root can be very problematic. I would recommend instead using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm) to install Node.js and NPM just for your individual user - that way you can easily switch between Node.js versions as necessary and don't need to run anything as root.